# How to implement accordions in Java swing

Tags: java, swing

I have implemented accordions in Java using the code from 
https://code.google.com/p/k-diapo/source/browse/trunk/kdiapo/src/View/AccordianPanel.java?r=17

But to this I have panels which I have designed which is in Null layout, when I inserted these panels into accordions it is fine but, when I re-size the frame, contents not getting re-sized in it.

This accordion I have place using grid-bag layout. Whole idea is to get re-size the components as window re-sized.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: No offence, but that linked code is a great example of what not to do. It should be implemented primarily as layout manager and should be updating the UI from outside the EDT

Comment: _i have designed which is in Null layout_ big mistake: **never-ever** do any manual sizing/locating, that's the exclusive task of a suitable LayoutManager

Comment: So to design accordions is there any other solutions?

Comment: Does it need to be Swing? JavaFX has it by default: https://o7planning.org/en/11055/javafx-accordion-tutorial